# Toggling React State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

consider this as my react state

```
state = {
a: true,
b: false,
c: false,
d: false,
e: false 
}
```

Now, I want to toggle the state on button click and if the event is equal to the key (a, b, c, d, e) in my state, I want that to be true and remaining to false. Currently what I am doing is..

```
someEvent = (event) => {
if (event === "a") this.setState({a: true, b: false, c: false, d: false, e: false})
if (event === "b")this.setState({a: false, b: true, c: false, d: false, e: false})
....
....
....
}
```

Instead of writing/setting every state to false, I want the given event equal to the key to have true value in my state and everything else to be false,

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this

```
let updateObject = [...this.state];
Object.keys( this.state )
        .map( Key => {
            if(event === this.state[Key]){
              updateObject[key] = true;
            }else{
              updateObject[key] = false;
            }
     } );
 });

this.setState({...this.state,updateObject});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by following code:

```
this.setState({
  a: event === "a",
  b: event === "b",
  c: event === "c",
  d: event === "d",
  e: event === "e"
});
```

Comment: @downvoters: Care to explain the reason for downvote? I can't seems to see the problem with this answer

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this requires writing out each state property. For a large number of properties, that might be tedious and error prone. But it's a great solution if there aren't many properties.

Answer (score 4):

Here with a one-liner.

Use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the array of keys from the object then iterate through the array to check if the event is equal to the state. If found then the state is true otherwise false;

```js
let event = 'c'
let state = { a: true, b: false, c: false, d: false, e: false }
Object.keys(state).forEach(s => state[s] = s === event)
console.log(state)
```

Comment: Don't you think calling `this.setState` for no of keys in the state will have performance concerns?

Comment: I don't quite understand. I have no background in reactjs, so sorry for that but I think this answer is useful more or less. Calling this.setState at the end of this code will work in my opinion. If you really concern about performance, I can optimize this a little bit more for you though.

Comment: I so appreciate your answer. setState re-renders our DOM (like it compares with virtual DOM and re-renders the changes). I have upvoted your answer though :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
Object.keys( this.state )
        .map( Key => {
            if(event === this.state[Key]){
              this.setState({this.state[Key] : true});
            }else{
              this.setState({this.state[Key] : false});
            }
     } );
 })
```

Comment: Don't you think calling `this.setState` for no of keys in the state will have performance concerns?

Comment: I have slightly improved my answer please check.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize an object with all states as false

```
const obj = {};
for (let char = 'a'; char <= 'e'; char++) obj[char] = false;
```

or based on the keys in this.state object

```
for (let key in this.state) obj[key] = false;
```

next set the state to true for whichever condition is valid

```
obj[event] = true;
```

now set the state

```
this.setState(obj);
```

PS: You should handle errors and events that might break the code here since I haven't added validation.

PS (2): This lets you save time, instead of writing each if/else or switch statement yourself.

Answer (score 1):

well you can simply do like that.

```
someEvent = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event]: true })
}
```

so if event === "a" then it will only setState for a
same for b, c, d, e this one condition will set all state for you.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you may be modeling your state inefficiently -- if there will always be one true value and everything else is false you could simply do:

```
state = {
  currentlyTrue: a
}
someEvent = (event) => {
  this.setState({currentlyTrue: event})
}
```

if you're set on your current state model, this should work. here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gmuhtxy/)

```
someEvent = (event) => {
  this.setState((previousState) => {
    Object.keys(previousState).forEach((v) => { previousState[v] = false })
    previousState[event] = true
    return previousState;
  })
}
```

Comment: Don't you think calling `this.setState` for no of keys in the state will have performance concerns?

Comment: I'm only calling setState one time though - I'm just mutating the previousState object to get it to the desired end result before returning it.